# Compressing multiple IF statement

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have about 40 different parameters that I have to check whether if it is within a range or not. The range are all different values. The IF statements below will go up to 30-40 depending on how many parameters I have. The responses may not be in running order. I may have to pick responses from different column. It can be `Column 1,2,6,8,12,20` not necessarily `Column 1,2,3,4,5,6` etc

What are some ways I can reduce the number of `IFs` statement to optimize my code?

A sample:

````
 var speed1template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('speed1');
  speed1template.speed1 = values[1];

  if((values[1] >= 100) || (values[1] <= 50)){

    MailApp.sendEmail("someone@gmail.com",
    "Out of Range Notification",
     "",{htmlBody: speed1template.evaluate().getContent()});

  }

   var temperaturetemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('temperature');
  temperaturetemplate.temperature = values[2];

  if((values[2] >= 10) || (values[2] <= 5)){

    MailApp.sendEmail("someone@gmail.com",
    "Out of Range Notification",
     "",{htmlBody: temperaturetemplate.evaluate().getContent()});

  }

   var voltagetemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('voltage');
  voltagetemplate.voltage = values[3];

  if((values[3]>= 500)){

    MailApp.sendEmail("someone@gmail.com",
    "Out of Range Notification",
     "",{htmlBody: speed1template.evaluate().getContent()});

  }```
````

Comment: Consider adding a `validate()` function to the `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile`; `voltagetemplate.validate(values[3])` or `speed1template.validate(values[1])`... you could also move the "out of range" logic to that validate function. **tl;dr** JavaScript is a functional language, my first suggestion is almost always write a function.

Comment: you can try to maintain a list of objects, each object containing what is variable in your model : the template name, the lower and upper limits, the recipient of mail, and whatever you need. and then loop over this list. just as sweeper suggested

Comment: @Tuckbros - I am trying right now but the HTML Template is giving an issue. It accepts only String. But name itself when gets passed down to the ``rangeChecks.name`` is not a string

Comment: rangeCheck.name with no "s". with the "s" it is the whole list not the current item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick here is to transform each if statement into an object. Find out what's different about each if statement. Well, we can see that each has a column name that changes (`speed1`, `temperature`, `voltage`), a different number (`value[1]`, `value[2]`, `value[3]`), and a different range of valid values.

So we need to put these values into an array of objects.

```
var rangeChecks = [
    {
        name: "speed1",
        number: 1,
        max: 100,
        min: 50
    },
    {
        ...
    },
    ...
];
```

If there isn't a min, such as for `voltage`, you can use `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` instead.

Then, we loop through `rangeChecks` and use only one if statement:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < rangeChecks.length ; i++) {
    var rangeCheck = rangeChecks[i];
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(rangeCheck.name);
    template[rangeCheck.name] = values[rangeCheck.number];

    if((values[rangeCheck.number] >= rangeCheck.max) || (values[rangeCheck.number] <= rangeCheck.min)){

    MailApp.sendEmail("someone@gmail.com",
    "Out of Range Notification",
     "",{htmlBody: template.evaluate().getContent()});

    }
}
```

Comment: So with this, I will have long list of data in rangeChecks right? And yes some of them has only an upper limit or a lower limit not both limits. For the ``HtmlService``, each parameter has its own template of email that I need to use.

Comment: @D3FTY Yes you have understood correctly. Does it work?

Comment: I will try this out on a test form with several questions and get back to you. Thank you!

Comment: ``No HTML file named undefined was found.`` This issue came up. My HTML files are the same as what is under the ``name:`` ``HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile`` needs a String Filename. @Sweeper

Comment: @D3FTY Which line did that come from? The `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(rangeCheck.name);` line?

Comment: @D3FTY Maybe you have misspelled `rangeCheck.name` as `rangeChecks.name`? You can try using a normal for loop instead of a for...in loop.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the ``for (rangeCheck in rangeChecks)``?
I used a normal for loop as such, ``for(z =0; z <5; z++){
//code
}``

Comment: @D3FTY I have converted the for loop in my answer. See the edit.

Comment: Ah, the loop is exactly like mine. I miss this out ``var rangeCheck = rangeChecks[i];``

Comment: Lat question, if I have 50 parameters, I will be using this ``for(var i = 0; i <50; i++){
   values[i] = e.values[i];
  }``

But, what if I have 50 parameters and I only need 25 but not in order? I just have to number them correctly under the array of objects based on which column yes?

Comment: @D3FTY you just have number them correctly in the array of objects. As you can see, I never accessed `values[i]`, it’s always `values[rangeCheck.number]`.

Comment: But I still need to have the ``FOR`` loop to extract the data from ``onFormSubmit`` and assign to ``var values`` isn't it? This ``FOR`` loop, is for me to extract data from my spreadsheet on form submission.

Comment: @D3FTY oh you are talking about another for loop! You didn’t show it, so I don’t know. And I suspect that it is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: I think it is. But ``values`` is actually a variable that I used in another for loop, to extract the data i need from spreadsheet and assigning it to a variable for the script, without that I don't think the ``values[rangeCheck.number]`` will not work. But thanks a lot man. This helped me a lot in making things not confusing with loads of variables and also IF statements.

Comment: Sorry.I can't find ``Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`` in Google Script. Is there something else to this?

Comment: @D3FTY google script might not support it then. Try to find the equivalent in google script.

Comment: @D3FTY , Sweeper It supports. What do you mean  *can't find*?

Comment: @TheMaster - I tried, it didn't give my any logs. No errors too.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to optimise further

if you had the same condition and requirement for all the values, it's super easy for you. but with a different set of conditions in hand, you have to specify each condition. separate IFs will be the best-optimised way for that.

Comment: Is it due to the fact that it has different condition and requirements?

Comment: yeah, exactly if you had the same condition and requirement for all the values, it's super easy for you. but with a different set of conditions in hand, you have to specify each condition. separate IFs will be the best-optimised way for that.

Comment: Check the solution above. Thanks.